# Eclipse SWT - exported .jar fails to import methods

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, bukkit

I've got the SWT file ".jar" added on to my project as an external jar. So it's imported into my project and I can call it's method via:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
```

There are no import errors when I do this so I suspect everything is working accordingly. However, when I export this as a ".jar" and use it, there are errors saying that the "org.eclipse.swt.[etc]..." don't exist.

I'm trying to make a Bukkit plugin that uses a GUI (SWT) and I have no idea why this isn't working - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After you ran your main class in eclipse just go to `File > Export > Runnable JAR`. Select the matching configuration to your file.
You should get that :

[image]

If you need to load swt dynamically:

```
public static String getArchFilename(String prefix) 
{ 
   return prefix + "_" + getOSName() + "_" + getArchName() + ".jar"; 
} 

private static String getOSName() 
{ 
   String osNameProperty = System.getProperty("os.name"); 

   if (osNameProperty == null) 
   { 
       throw new RuntimeException("os.name property is not set"); 
   } 
   else 
   { 
       osNameProperty = osNameProperty.toLowerCase(); 
   } 

   if (osNameProperty.contains("win")) 
   { 
       return "win"; 
   } 
   else if (osNameProperty.contains("mac")) 
   { 
       return "osx"; 
   } 
   else if (osNameProperty.contains("linux") || osNameProperty.contains("nix")) 
   { 
       return "linux"; 
   } 
   else 
   { 
       throw new RuntimeException("Unknown OS name: " + osNameProperty); 
   } 
} 

private static String getArchName() 
{ 
   String osArch = System.getProperty("os.arch"); 

   if (osArch != null && osArch.contains("64")) 
   { 
       return "64"; 
   } 
   else 
   { 
       return "32"; 
   } 
}
public static void addJarToClasspath(File jarFile) 
{ 
   try 
   { 
       URL url = jarFile.toURI().toURL(); 
       URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(); 
       Class<?> urlClass = URLClassLoader.class; 
       Method method = urlClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class<?>[] { URL.class }); 
       method.setAccessible(true);         
       method.invoke(urlClassLoader, new Object[] { url });             
   } 
   catch (Throwable t) 
   { 
       t.printStackTrace(); 
   } 
}
```

Then :

```
File swtJar = new File(getArchFilename("lib/swt")); 
addJarToClasspath(swtJar);
```

assuming te structure outside the jar is :

```
lib/swt_win_32.jar 
lib/swt_win_64.jar 
lib/swt_linux_32.jar 
lib/swt_linux_64.jar
```

From http://www.chrisnewland.com/select-correct-swt-jar-for-your-os-and-jvm-at-runtime-191

Comment: Is it not possible to export this as a .jar (not runnable) and initialise it through a method?

Comment: This doesn't really help - the problem is that when I initialise the actual SWT there's an error saying that the methods don't exist - it's not finding the actual classes from SWT.

Comment: The first method is useless - I've got the Jars, I just need to initialise the actual SWT. The error occurs when calling the SWT functions, it says they can't be found.

Comment: Does it works or not ? Apart from whatyou wanted at the beginning.

Comment: No it doesn't... I don't think you understand the problem

Comment: It didn't work though because it's not related to my problem.